# Not able to call out array headers in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

Okay - this is a really weird issue - and it probably has a really stupid solution.

But i import a csv

```
$csv = import-csv c:\users\hello.csv
```

Then i have an array of words, for which i am wanting to use to search through the csv - and if there's a match in the csv - populate an adjacent column in the csv.

here's the array:

```
$newhandles
hi
hello
```

now - if i run a foreach loop with an if statement inside of it - it doesn't recognize one of the headers.

```
foreach ($newhandle in $newhandles) 
{if ($csv.name -eq $newhandle) {$csv.redundant = $newhandle}}
```

however it gives me this error:

```
The property 'redundant' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists 
and can be set.
At line:1 char:69
+ ... andles) {if ($csv.name -eq $newhandle) {$csv.redundant = $newhandle}}
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

I know the property exists - because if i call it directly - it shows three empty slots - and if i call something to it directly - the element will populate. such as

```
> $csv[0].redundant = 'hi'

> $csv[0]


name        : hi
description : don't settle
system      : sight
redundant   : hi
tags        :
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when manually checking you append [0], but in the If you simply reference the whole $csv.Name. What happens when you manually enter $csv.Name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this foreach loop :

```
foreach ($rec in $csv){
if($newhandles -contains $rec.name){
$rec.redundant = $rec.name

}

}
```

if you check ($csv.redundant).GetType(),you can see that it returns an array instead of the property you want but when you are assigning value to  $csv[0].redundant you are accessing the exact property and that's why it works when you tested manually

Comment: ahh - so you need to do the foreach on the actual csv to break it down into each of ITS records to be able to access each of its properties. Why would $newhandles be in front of -contains $rec.name though? shouldn't that be if ($rec.name -contains $newhandles)? (not that it matters that much now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import-csv "c:\users\hello.csv" | select * , @{N="redundant";E={if ($newhandles -contains $_.Name) {$_.Name} else {$null}}} -ExcludeProperty redundant
```